# Does Suzaku have some relationship with Geass?

Tags: code-geass

In episode 22 of *Code Geass: Lelouch of the Rebellion R1*, before Geass went out of control, CC wanted to say something to Suzaku.

> I need to know one thing! Are you the–

Does that mean that Suzaku have some relationship with Geass?